# Resizing an Ext.js Panel using Ext.EventManager.onWindowResize

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'v been trying to get my Data Grid table to resize with the window using `Ext.EventManager.onWindowResize`. I can easily get the height and width of the window then the browser resizes but I can't seem to find a way to resize the grid.

The grid itself is created from an instance of the Ext.grid.Panel class

```
   var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {});

   Ext.EventManager.onWindowResize(function () {

      var w = Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width;
      var h = Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height;

      console.log(grid);

      Ext.getCmp('grid-id').setSize(w, h);

  });
```

I was trying this piece of code by it it returns an error because there is no setSize method on this object it seems.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setWidth()` and `setHeight()` function of grid to set the width & height of the grid.